# Xamarin Persian Datepicker

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, datepicker

I searched a lot about persian datepicker to use in Android app which is written in c# with Xamarin. but I couldn't find.

I also searched for a mean to change the date object which is used in default datepicker and there was no hope too.

do you know any shamsi (persian) datepicker for Xamarin or any way to extend default datepicker or changing calendar?

Comment: What means persian datepicker? What is the difference between persian and standard one?

Comment: Persian or Shamsi or Jalali Calendar is 360-based calendar, its era, date and months name are totally different with Georgian's. for example today is September 27th 2015 but in Shamsi Calendar it is Mehr 5th 1394. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iranian_calendars

Answer (score 4):

I've been downloaded `PersianMaterialDateTimePicker`
and converted to `dll` with `Visual Studio`.
So you can download this `dll` and use it.

Example:

```
Com.Mohamadamin.Persianmaterialdatetimepicker.Date.DatePickerDialog d = new Com.Mohamadamin.Persianmaterialdatetimepicker.Date.DatePickerDialog();
d.Show(FragmentManager, "test");
```

You can download the dll from here:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/48774/another-calendar-type-for-datepicker

Comment: dont forget you must add

Xamarin.Android.Support.v4

so you can install the

Xamarin.Bindings.MaterialDateTimePicker

this package automatically install  Xamarin.Android.Support.v4

Comment: it just works on xamarin android, not xamrin forms. :(